# Batch: FOR /R doesn't work with a variable in the path

Tags: variables, loops, batch-file

An example:

```
FOR %%i IN (3) DO (
    ECHO %%i
    FOR /R "C:\backup\server%%i\temp" %%? IN (*.bak) DO (
        REM some code...
    )
)
```

Result of `ECHO`: `3`.

Result of second `FOR`: **the code isn't executed**.

But with:

```
FOR %%i IN (3) DO (
    ECHO %%i
    FOR /R "C:\backup\server3\temp" %%? IN (*.bak) DO (
        REM some code...
    )
)
```

Result of `ECHO`: `3`.

Result of second `FOR`: **the code is executed**.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only solution i've found:

```
FOR %%i IN (3) DO (
    PUSHD "C:\backup\server%%i\temp"
    FOR /R %%g IN (*.bak) DO (
        REM some code...
    )
    POPD
)
```

Doc: http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

> If the [drive:]path are not specified they will default to the current
> drive:path.

**Edit:** I added `PUSHD`/`POPD` after dbenham has answered. Thanks to him.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the original code does not work is because the directory for the FOR /R option must be known at the time the FOR is parsed, but the %%i variable is not expanded until ***after*** the FOR statement has already been parsed. The same problem exists for the adarshr suggestion - !suffix! is not expanded until after the FOR statement has been parsed.

The GG answer is a very good viable work-around. Perhaps could be improved with PUSHD followed by POPD at end, instead of CD. But only if needed.

The only other way I can think to get around the problem is something like this

```
@echo off
FOR %%i IN (3) DO call :innerLoop %%i
exit /b

:innerLoop
FOR /R "C:\backup\server%1\temp" %%? IN (*.bak) DO (
  REM some code...
)
exit /b
```

But I don't like to use CALL unless I have to because it is inefficient. I like the CD solution.

Answer (score 1):

For /f is always more flexible than FOR /R like this:

```
FOR %%i IN (3) DO (
   FOR /f "delims=" %%? IN ('DIR /s/b "C:\server%%i\*.bak"')  DO (
      ECHO %%?
   )
)
```

Output:

C:\server3\1.bak

C:\server3\subfolder\2.bak

Also, to search recursively for more than one file type:

```
FOR %%i IN (3) DO (
   FOR /f "delims=" %%? IN ('DIR /s/b "C:\server%%i\*.bak","C:\server%%i\*.htm"')  DO (
      ECHO %%?
   )
)
```

Output:

C:\server3\1.bak

C:\server3\subfolder\2.bak

C:\server3\subfolder\1.htm

Comment: Helped me with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169690/batch-scripting-variable-in-a-nested-for-r-loop-definition

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be setting `EnableDelayedExpansion` on?

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%i IN (3) DO (
    SET suffix=%%i
    ECHO !suffix!
    FOR /R "C:\backup\server!suffix!\temp" %%? IN (*.bak) DO (
        REM some code...
    )
)
```

Comment: what is the output of `echo !suffix!`? Does it print anything at all?

Comment: It prints 3 but the loop dosen't work. `ECHO "C:\backup\server!suffix!\temp"` prints `"C:\backup\server3\temp"`.

Comment: It works for you? I copy and paste your code, with replacing `REM some code...` by `ECHO foo`: I doesn't enter in the loop.

Comment: I hope you replaced `%%?` with something like `%%k`

Comment: I found a workaround: I do a `CD "C:\backup\server%%i\temp"` and a loop without path `FOR /R %%? IN (*.bak) DO ( ... )`. It works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Delayed expansion cannot work because the directory must be known at parse time. See my answer.