# Windows batch script nested for loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying make a batch file which will loop through a folder for subfolders naming starts with "Mode" and then copy all the files inside those folders to another location. I have wrote a nested loop for the purpose but unable to understand where I'm making the thing wrong. Can you guys please point me out?

```
set _src_res_path=C:\Sample-Input-Folder
set _dst_res_path=C:\Sample-Output-Folder

for /d %%M in ("%_src_res_path%\XmlFiles\English\Mode*") do (
    echo 1.. %%M
    pause
    for /r "%%M" %%N in (*.xml) do (
        echo 2.. %%N
        pause
        copy /y "%%N" "%_dst_res_path%\XmlFiles\English"
        rmdir "%%N" /s /q
    )
)
```

Comment: It never hits the echo 2.. %%N line. Can't figure out what I'm missng.

Comment: Just used push, pop method for 'for /r' loop. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588927/batch-for-r-doesnt-work-with-a-variable-in-the-path

Answer (score 0):

To copy files from folders starting with `mode` test this: remove `echo` after testing it to see what it prints to the console:

```
@echo off
for /d /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (mode*) do echo copy "%%a\*.*" "d:\target"
pause
```